# Is there any tool to statically extract java code components?

Tags: java

```
class A {
  int foo(@Nullable int b) {...}
}
```

And I want to get these information:
Class contains method foo, foo's return type is int, foo has a parameter b which is int annotated with Nullable, and the implementation is ...

I have a project need to refactor from one framework to another framework and I want to do it automatically, first thing is to get all these components and I can regenerate the code. I am thinking to do regular expression matching, but wonder is there any tool that already did that?

Comment: You could use Java's own reflection methods

Comment: not any java framework I know can help, what you want is more like file search. You could try to write a shell script to help.  recommend a tool https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher, search file content very fast, easy to use, try it.

Comment: Hi Johannes, thanks! Java reflection methods does not come with implementation .. I turns out use the combination of java reflection and regex to extract things out and do my refactoring

Hi Patrick, our company has a very good internal code search app to search the codes, but thanks  for the recommendation.